# Parse PFObject ID to map annotation title & subtitle

Tags: objective-c, parsing, mapkit, objectid

I'm using the parse framework to collect objects in a class and display them on a map. Currently, the annotation titles display the "CreatedAt" string, and the subtitles display the "coordinates". How can I change the title and subtitle to another PFObject ID that I've set? I've based a lot of my code on the GeoLocations app that Parse have supplied. The code is as follows:

```
@interface GeoPointAnnotation()
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *object;
@end

@implementation GeoPointAnnotation

- (id)initWithObject:(PFObject *)aObject {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _object = aObject;

        PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = self.object[@"coordinates"];
        [self setGeoPoint:geoPoint];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setGeoPoint:(PFGeoPoint *)geoPoint {
    _coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);

    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    if (dateFormatter == nil) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    }

    static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = nil;
    if (numberFormatter == nil) {
        numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;
    }

    _title = [dateFormatter stringForObjectValue:self.object.createdAt];
    _subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:geoPoint.latitude]],
                 [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:geoPoint.longitude]]];    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by replacing some of the code with this:

```
 static NSString *dateFormatter = nil;
if (dateFormatter == nil) {
    dateFormatter = [[NSString alloc] init];

}
```

and then this:

```
_title = [dateFormatter stringByAppendingString:self.object[@"Name"]];

_subtitle = [dateFormatter stringByAppendingString:self.object[@"Location"]];
```